# How to override wifi broadcast speed limit?

Tags: wireless

In the 802.11 protocol broadcast happens at minimum speeds (usually 1 Mbps) since there is no ACK system to know if the packet has been delivered successfully.

But I want to broadcast a video stream and higher error rates are not a problem for my application, and I would prefer higher speeds to lower error rates (I will handle the error correction on higher layers with my own codes).

I have set up an access point using "Hostapd" and a 802.11n wifi dongle in linux on a raspberry pi 2 and wanted to know if there is a way to change the broadcast speed limit so I can do the broadcast in higher speeds.

Answer (score 1):

likely wifi is not your limiting factor.

802.11n = 600 mbps

USB 2.0 = 480 mbps

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

Comment: The problem is broadcast happens at 1 Mbps. I'll be happy at rates of around 30 Mbps.

Comment: use udp and more cpu intensive temporal encoding (x264), traiding bandwidth for error rate is not going to work as you want an that level of the network stack... there is some cusom router work along these lines...